Is Alien on Disney+ brighter than the original?
I just rewatched Alien for the gazillionth time. This time on Disney+ after I watched it on VHS and DVD many times.
Many scenes were brighter than I remembered them, leading to the Alien often being in plain sight and making the limited special effects quite obvious.
In my memory, everything was so dark that I could hardly make out any details, contributing a lot to the suspension of disbelief.
Is my memory at fault? Or did Disney tinker with the movie? Or something else?

Good chance you're watching it on a different TV with modern things like HDR and 4K, and that's not to mention that your settings could be different. Do you still have access to those DVD or VHS to try with the same screen?

Not right now, and I doubt can hook them up ...
